# page displays blank fields before form POST JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, weblogic

Is there any reason why a form POST will cause the page to display empty fields before moving to next page?

To rephrase the issue, the user types values for all fields in page A then clicks next on the screen, which causes the form to be posted to server and the user sees the next page B but before that there is slight delay like one second or slightly more, where the user still sees page A with empty fields with placeholder text not the actual values entered by user. The values are properly posted on the server and curated content is displayed in page B.

The web application is written in spring mvc 3.2 and uses JSP, tiles 3.0.3, javascript, 18next.js. Runs on Weblogic 11g.
This is a legacy application, I tried something locally with spring boot and Jetty to test form POST but couldn't recreate it. Not sure if its Weblogic related.

I have tried disabling all client side validations to see if that is causing the delay and display of empty fields but it didn't help, same issue.

Sorry, I couldn't paste any spring/tiles configurations here.
I couldn't find any solution in my search for these keywords "page displays blank fields before form POST JSP". 
I just want to find if anyone has faced this issue before and overcame it.

Comment: It is not weblogic related, I confirmed by writing some test pages and test controller in the same project and the issue is not there in these test pages. Should be because of some javascript.

Comment: yes it was because of an on page unload event handler that emptied values of text fields.

Answer (score 0):

It was because of a

```js
$(window).on('beforeunload',function(){
// empty out text and password fields
});
```

in a javascript file loaded with the JSPs.

Issue identified, no further investigations required.

Comment: You could also try adding binding result param in your controller to make sure that data is present .